# readFile method does not show results at console

Tags: java, file-io

This is my question :

```
     a method readLine that reads a line from the file specified in fileName and returns the line a String.
```

What I am trying to do is I read and write some info into text file using eclipse. And here are my codes :

```
    public class FileController {
private String fileName;

public FileController(){
    String fileName = "student.txt";
}

public FileController(String fileName){
    this.fileName = fileName;
}

public String readLine(){
    String line ="";
    try{
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(fr);
        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            Student stud = new Student(sc.nextLine());
            line = stud.toString();
        }
        fr.close();
    }catch(FileNotFoundException exception){
        System.out.println("File " + fileName + " was not found");
    }catch(IOException exception){
        System.out.println(exception);
    }
    return line;
}

public void writeLine(String input){
    try{
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName,true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(bw);

        outFile.println(input);
        outFile.close();
    }catch(IOException exception){
        System.out.println(exception);
    }
}

public static void main (String [] args){
    FileController fc = new FileController("student.txt");
    String input = "1234567H;Gabriel;23/12/1994;56;67;87";
    fc.readLine();
    fc.writeLine(input);
}
```

This works perfectly by adding the record into the text file. However, the console there doesn't shows the result. So from what I know it's the mistake was at readLine(). When I used void it works perfectly. But the question requests me to return a String. Anybody know how to solve this?

- when I do println within the while loop there's record stored in there. I guess the programme took the String file= ""; this line and return the result. So how can I take the result of line in while loop and replace with the initialization?

Comment: I'm not sure what you expecting see...You never assign the the return value from `fc.readLine()` to anything, not do you use `System.out.println` to display the result from the read...

Comment: I added the println method already. But the result just keep showing the last line only. It doesn't show up the previous records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the line in while loop:

```
try{
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(fr);
        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            Student stud = new Student(sc.nextLine());
            line = stud.toString();
        }
```

So this means that only last line will get passed to student [most likely blank line] and it might not print anything or even an exception might come. Use StringBuffer and append the string and then return that.

EDIT:

Try this.

```
public String readLine(){
    StringBuffer line =new StringBuffer();
    try{
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(fr);
        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            Student stud = new Student(sc.nextLine());
            line.append(stud.toString());
        }
        fr.close();
    }catch(FileNotFoundException exception){
        System.out.println("File " + fileName + " was not found");
    }catch(IOException exception){
        System.out.println(exception);
    }
    return line.toString();
}
```

EDIT:
 If above code also returns blank then most likely issue is Strudent "toString()" method. It might be returning blank.

EDIT:

```
public String readLine(){
        StringBuffer line =new StringBuffer();
        try{
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(fr);
            while(sc.hasNextLine()){
                Student stud = new Student(sc.nextLine());
                line.append(stud.toString());
                line.append("\n");
            }
            fr.close();
        }catch(FileNotFoundException exception){
            System.out.println("File " + fileName + " was not found");
        }catch(IOException exception){
            System.out.println(exception);
        }
        return line.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Can you give me some example?

Comment: But the result just keep appending. For example, 1234567H Gabriel 701234567H Gabriel 701234567H Gabriel 70. Can make it like nextLine?

Comment: Your question states, you are not getting nay output. Is that resolved?

Comment: Ya exactly. Sorry because I didnt mentioned above

Comment: I solved it by adding line.append(System.getProperty("line.separator")); . And ya, yours works too, I prefer yours since it seems much more clearer for a rookie.Thanks.

Comment: Just adding "line.append("\n");" will also be sufficient. Can you mark it as answered then?

Comment: You could return an array of String instead